# does a content resolver change it's primary key

Tags: sqlite, android-contentresolver

I'm trying to setup a virtual interface for the database for all the music files using a content resolver. But, I have a small issue which I realized it *could* happen after developing a lot.

I was using `MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID` as the primary key which linked to multiple `sqlite` databases , now I wonder if the system *could* rearrange the keys (even when the data isn't modified/renamed/deleted) at some point.

Say for example `x/y/z/a.mp3` had this `MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID= 1` but after some time  can the file have some other value assigned to this `_ID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*_ID* is the unique id for the row and will not change unless you force it to.

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/provider/BaseColumns#_ID:kotlin.String